# Proof that $f(a)$ = $a$ div $d$ is onto

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

i wanted to ask here if this proving process were correct:

$f(a)= $ $a$ **div** $d$

We must show this is an onto function

If it is onto, then $\forall y$ in the codomain, $\exists a$ in the domain such that $f(a)=y$

Consider an arbitrary $y$ in the codomain. We know that $f(a)=y$ if and only if $a$ **div** $d$ $= y$.

$a$ **div** $d = y$ implies that $a= dy + r$ .

But then $f(dy+r)= y$ because:

$f(dy+r)$= $(dy+r)$ **div** $d$ meanining that

$dy+r= dq+k$  where $q$ = $(dy+r)$ **div** $d$

Now since $a=dy+r$, $a$ **mod** $d$ is equal to $(dy+r)$ **mod** $d$ so $k=r$

This means that:

$dy+r=dq+r$, so the quotient $q$ of $dy+r$ is $y$. But then $f(dy+r)=y$, so for an arbitray $y$, there is an element  $dy+r$ in the domain such that $f(dy+r)$ is $y$, as we wanted to show.

Are the proof's steps correct.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning (insofar as I can understand it) is circular. First you say

$$ \text{ div } = \text{ implies that } =+$$

without specifying any particular $a$ whose existence you want to prove.

Then you end with
$$
\text{ for an arbitrary } , \text{ there is an element }+ \ldots
$$

but you never did actually point out such an element.

Here's a hint. What is the remainder when you divide $a=3$ by $d=7$?

Comment: Thanks, probably the reasoning is not correct. I can't manage to find the answer though. I will do other tries

Comment: @PwNzDust You're welcome. I suggest your next try should begin with my hint. Find an integer $a$ that leaves a remainder of $3$ when you divide it by $7$.